# ngx-tree view check box should be false by default

Tags: angular

I used this code:

```
<ngx-treeview [config]="config" [items]="items" (selectedChange)="values = $event">
</ngx-treeview>
```

Everything works fine but all the nodes check box is checked by default. I want the check box to be unchecked by default.

This is my Json Object.

```
[
  {
    "value": "1022",
    "text": "ABC",
    "children": [
      {
        "value": "1023",
        "text": "BBC"

      },
      {
        "value": "1024",
        "text": "BCB",
        "children": [
          {
            "value": "1025",
            "text": "ccB"

          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Please do not ask me to alter the JSON object.

Comment: Did you find out the solution?

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me:
Convert your result into the TreeviewItem list, pass this list to the below method.

```
let TreeViewItems: Array<TreeviewItem> = new Array<TreeviewItem>();
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  TreeViewItems.push(new TreeviewItem(result[i]));
}

uncheckAllItems(TreeViewItems);

uncheckAllItems(items) {
    items.forEach(element => {
      element.checked = false;
      element.collapsed = true
      if (element.internalChildren) {
        this.uncheckAllItems(element.internalChildren);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a short description how to implement your solution as it is just a blank method.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no option for checkbox value in config.

If you change your ngx-tree file you can easily make it false as default value.
Get in lib file in src. Update "**private internalChecked**" as "**false**" in "**treeview-item.ts**" file.

It should make false as default value but as I say it is temporary solution until updating config options.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `checked = false` to parent and child elements after initializing your `[items]="items"`

```
this.items.forEach(item => {
  item.checked = false;
  item["internalChildren"].forEach(item => { item.checked = false; })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by simply hiding all checkboxes with css.

```css
:host ::ng-deep ngx-treeview-item .form-check-input {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `checked = false` to your Items

```js
const iWarehouse1 = new TreeviewItem({
            text: 'Warehouse 001',
            value: 9,
            checked: false,
            children: [
                {
                    text: 'Shelf 001',
                    value: 91,
                    checked: false,
                    children: [
                        {
                            text: 'Bin 001',
                            value: 911,
                            checked: false,
                        }
                    ],
                },
            ],
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS THE WORKING ANSWER!! Just add "checked: false" to your TreeView Item

const iWarehouse1 = new TreeviewItem({
text: 'Warehouse 001',
value: 9,
checked: false,
children: [
{
text: 'Shelf 001',
value: 91,
checked: false,
children: [
{
text: 'Bin 001',
value: 911,
checked: false,
}
],
},
],
});

Comment: Adding `checked: false` was advised by almost all of the other answers already.